# PhoneRTC Swift Compiler errors

Tags: swift, phonertc

Using Alon Gubkin's PhoneRTC plugin, but unable to build the application due to 20 Swift Compiler errors...I've seen others have had the same issues, so looking to see if anyone has a solution
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this library is not ready for Swift3

you have to rewrite the library to Swift3
( see https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/issues/216 )

Comment: Thanks...I'm hoping someone around here has successfully done so or that the original author will have an updated library soon